# set; debug shutdown in class property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

How can I turn off properties from going to 'set;' methods when debugging code with F11?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can step over properties:

[image]

Some more info: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/AutoStepOver.aspx